# Why is PASOE WebHandler escaping slashes in the JSON request content?

Tags: escaping, progress-4gl, openedge, backslash

I'm using Progress OpenEdge 11.6.1 on Windows Server 2012. I'm converting some APIs that used the REST Adapter to now use a PASOE WebHandler. The same JSON request content is giving different results between the two. In the request I pass a Progress-formatted date, such as

```
"FieldValue": "11/30/2016"
```

The REST adapter API gets that exact value for the date and processes it successfully. However the WebHandler API gets

```
11\/30\/2016
```

The slashes appear to be escaped with backslashes, which causes an invalid date error. How can I avoid this? Do I have to write a function to strip the backslashes or is there a setting I can change to prevent the escaping?

Comment: This could be a bug. If possible you should log a support case with Progress.

Answer (score 1):

I was using the GetJsonText() method to read the input values from the JSON request content, which apparently returns the raw text with escaped characters. I changed it to the GetCharacter() method and the escaped characters were removed.